# rvest: scraping multiple tables with preceding titles

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, rselenium

I would like to scrape the this url: https://prog.nfz.gov.pl/app-jgp/GrupaSzczegoly.aspx?id=2AfRAM1JYDoYzktSMvdOhFiPm2Fnh67q

It lists statistics of medical procedures in each region and html has the structure: title and the corresponding table, 16 times for all regions of the country.

In simplified html:

```
<div class="tytul">01 - NameOfDistrict_01</div> 

<table>
...
<tr>        
<td class="lewa">No. of procedures</td>        
<td class="prawa"><span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_lblbw">950</span>
</td>
...
</table>


<div class="tytul">02 - NameOfDistrict_02</div> 
<table>
<tr>        
...
<tr>        
<td class="lewa">No. of procedures</td>        
<td class="prawa"><span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_lblbw">350</span>
</td>
...
</td>
</table>


<div class="tytul">nn - NameOfDistrict_nn</div>
<table>
...
<tr>        
<td class="lewa">No. of procedures</td>        
<td class="prawa"><span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_lblbw">850</span>
</td>
...
</table>
```

I do not need to scrape the whole tables (it would be fine if I could) I only need one or two values from them so I tried to look with Selector Gadget inspect the page.  One of the values I am interested in is number of procedures present in a nodes **#ContentPlaceHolder1_lblbw** and is preceded by a title i.e. **.tytul** class.

```
mydata <- read_html(....)  %>%  html_nodes(name, "#ContentPlaceHolder1_lblbw") %>%  
  html_text()
```

But this placeholder repeats for each region. I need then to read the first such placeholder after the title above the table. And record each title and the table that follow.

How to scrape such table to the dataframe

```
    District            No. of procedures
    NameOfDistrict_01   950
    NameOfDistrict_02   350
............................
    NameOfDistrict_nn   850
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this does what you are looking for.

```
library(rvest)
page <- read_html("https://prog.nfz.gov.pl/app-jgp/GrupaSzczegoly.aspx?id=2AfRAM1JYDoYzktSMvdOhFiPm2Fnh67q",encoding=-"utf-8")
data <- page %>% html_nodes(xpath='//*[@id="ContentPlaceHolder1_lblbp"]') %>% html_text()
titles <- page %>% html_nodes(xpath='//*[@class="tytul"]') %>% html_text()

myData <- data.frame(title=titles,data=as.numeric(data))

head(myData)
                   title data
1       01 - DOLNOSLASKI  919
2 02 - KUJAWSKO-POMORSKI  984
3          03 - LUBELSKI 1476
4           04 - LUBUSKI  255
5            05 - LÓDZKI 1225
6        06 - MALOPOLSKI 1780
```

Comment: That simple? I was thinking a loop or two would be necessary. Thanks very much.